# Installing DotNetZip on IIS ASP Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am running IIS v7.5 and using ASP.NET. I wanted to be able to create encrypted Zip files so I did some research and found this: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/.

I am completely new to IIS (Primarily a PHP developer on Linux) and I have no clue how to install this module. I have tried a number of things for a few hours now and all of them tend to either not work at all or just causes errors in IIS.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install anything on server, ASP.NET project is compiled on your development machine, and you publish only binaries and script / html / image / etc. files to server (there is no need for source code on server). There is a publish option in Visual Studio (right click on project in Solution explorer, and choose Publish).

So you have to include dotnetzip in your project, simplest way is to use NuGet, you can do this inside Visual Studio, right mouse click on project in VS Solution Explorer and choose "Manage NuGet packages", find dotnetzip package (online tab) include it in project and you are good to go :)

Comment: Ah I see. I don't use VS to code C# though (I use a standard text editor). What do I do with the .dll?

Comment: frankly, I don't know, try to use VS Express, it's free. http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Comment: @Zinglish: If you aren't using VS, then you're likely not compiling your code down before publishing it to the server which (although possible) not the right way to do things.  c#/asp.net shouldn't be leveraged the same way php is.

Answer (score 0):

As I grasped You do compile your program "manually", so in order to add reference `/r` switch should be used, for example:

```
csc Program.cs /r:DotNetZip.dll
```